# How can I add precision and scale to a decimal column without losing data in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, rails-migrations

I want to add precision and scale to some existing decimal columns in Rails 3 with SQLite. I've tried 3 different approaches, but have not been able to permanently affect the schema.

First, I tried just adding the precision and scale in the original migrations and schema.rb. This seemed reasonable since right now my database is SQLite and the column types aren't too important. However, next time I ran rake db:migrate, the precision and scale were removed from those columns in schema.rb.

Next, I tried running a new migration something like this:

```
def up
  change_table :my_table do |t|
    t.change :my_column, :decimal, precision: 15, scale: 2
  end
end
```

However, running this migration had no effect on schema.rb except to change the version. So I tried something similar:

```
def up
  change_column :my_table, :my_column, :decimal, precision: 15, scale: 2
end
```

but with the same result: no change to schema.rb except for the version number.

How can I add precision and scale to my decimal columns without re-running all the migrations? I need the schema to be right going forward, but without losing data.

Comment: Does SQLite even support precision and scale for decimal columns? I know SQLite is the default database but it really isn't suitable if you need strict data types like `decimal(m,n)`.

Comment: Right, the precision and scale are definitely not enforced by SQLite. I don't even know if ActiveRecord is enforcing it on the data. And SQLite is not a long term solution for this app.

Comment: Rails doesn't care what your migrations say, it just asks the database what the columns look like and goes from there. I don't think Rails will enforce `:limit`, `:precision`, `:scale`, or any of that stuff itself, you need to use validations for that **and** have it constrained in the database (DRY be damned, your code and your database shouldn't trust each other any more than they have to). I'd recommend that you switch to PostgreSQL right now, that's the strictest free database and strict is what you want your database to be.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help, but I don't think that gets me out of my current jam. In fact, switching to another database is exactly why it's important to get the schema right. Maybe I could just hack it together for a one time transfer to a new database, but it makes me uneasy that the next time I run a migration, my schema will be wrong.